# Absolute value optimization

Tags: computational-complexity, linear-programming

If you have an LP

Maximize/Minimize:

$c_1|x_1| + c_2|x_2| ... c_n|x_n|$

Subject to:

$Ax = b$

Can this be solved in polynomial time with respect to the amount of data used to represent the problem?

Comment: On average? Yes. In every case, I don't think so. See if [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex_algorithm#Efficiency) helps. Of course, simplex is not the only option, so ...

Comment: If Ax = b specifies a unit hypercube located in the all positive quadrant, with a corner at 0,0,0,0...0 and the absolute value was basically measuring the absolute value of $x_i - 1/2$ for all the $x_i$ in x

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For minimizing you can translate this to a standard linear program.

minimize
$\sum_i c_i y_i$ s.t. $Ax=b$, $y_i \ge x_i$, and $y_i \ge -x_i$.  $y_i = |x_i|$ in any optimal solution.  This is solvable in [polynomial time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid_method), but not by the simplex method, although that is likely the fastest method.

For maximizing absolute value you have a NP hard problem.  Consider the [number partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) problem.  If the values to be partitioned are $w_i$.  The optimization problem
maximize $\sum_i |x_i|$ subject to $\sum_i w_i x_i = 0$, $x_i \le 1$, and $x_i \ge -1$ will have an optimal value of $|I|$ if and only there is a partitioning of the $w_i$ into two equal subsets.

Comment: +1. I believe your answer is correct except that in the first part (minimize) the objective function should be $\min$ $\sum_i c_iy_i$ not $\sum_i c_i x_i$